# Spring REST API and i18n

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, internationalization

In my REST API I want to allow the user to set the locale using a `lang` parameter, i.e.

```
http://somehost/resource?param1=value1&lang=fr
```

If the `lang` parameter is not present in the URL then the `Accept-Language` header should be used and set as the Locale.

I'm using Spring's i18n features in my REST API. I have looked through the documentation and configured the necessary beans. If I send a request with the `Accept-Language` header it seems to work OK, when I call `LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()` it returns the locale I set in my header.

If I use the `lang` URL parameter it does not work.

How can I configure Spring to use the locale parameter too?

```
<bean id="localeInterceptor"     
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>

<bean     
 class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping" >
    <property name="interceptors">
        <list>
            <ref bean="localeInterceptor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionLocaleResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver"/>

<bean id="messages" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>messages</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions to try out. First, are you certain that the `LocaleChangeInterceptor` is getting invoked? Most of the configurations I've seen have an id of `handlerMapping` for the `HandlerMapping`. The other suggestion is concerning another id, namely `sessionLocaleResolver`, I think it should be `localeResolver`. I'm not sure if Spring relies on those id values or the class types by default for wiring all of this together, but it is worth a shot.